# Aggregate multiple Subversion logs into a single list

Tags: svn, logging

I have multiple SVN repositories and I'd like to gather some overall statistics from the logs. Basically I'd like to use Excel to make a graph of the number of commits per day, in all the repositories combined.

What I need is a simple way to fetch all the logs, combine them and get a formatted list with DATE, SVN REPOSITORY NAME and LOG MESSAGE. If that's XML or tab-delimited I can just paste it into Excel and work with that.

Is there a tool for this or am I going to have to write my own scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all that work, why not just take the three separate logs, note which repository each one came from, and then put them into one big list?

```
# For each repo:
svn log --xml --verbose > ~/svn-logs/result-$repo.xml

# Then:
cat *.xml > all-results.xml
```

You can then sort by the timestamps to get a holistic view of what things looked like over time.

Comment: That would be a lot of work and I'd like to be able to do this on a regular basis. Multiple = 20 to 30, not three.

Comment: In windows cmd something like for /somestupidoptionhere %%i in (repo1 repo2 repo3) do (svn log --xml --verbose blubblubblub).
Well, you still have to write out all repositories, but even with 30 it won't hurt.  Of course you could automate this part too, and if the repos change often, it would be a good idea indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `--xml` option to `svn log`.